# C equivalent to C++ decltype

Tags: c++, c, macros, decltype

In my C project, there is a struct, created by another colleague, containing some function pointers:

```
struct tools {  
    int (*tool_a) (int, int, int);
    ...
};
```

I have no right to change this struct and relative files.

Now I'm coding with the struct.
I have to define a function, whose return type and list of arguments must be the same with the `tools.tool_a`.
Meaning that my function must be as below:

```
int my_func(int, int, int);
```

The problem is that the struct changes a lot, especially the return types, for example `int` is replaced by `size_t` today, so I have to change my code a lot.

I know that `decltype` in C++ can help me so I just want to know if C has something equivalent?

I'm thinking I may use macro but I don't know how, I even don't know if it's possible or not.

## REAL CASE

I'm developing some testing tools for linux-kernel with C.
There have been many versions of custom kernels coming from other groups in my company. For historical reasons, some of them used `int`, others used `size_t` or `ssize_t` and so on.

Now when I code, I have to do like this:

```
// int my_func(int a, int b, int c)
size_t my_func(int a, int b, int c)
// ssize_t my_func(int a, int b, int c)
{}
struct tools my_tool = {
    .tool_a = my_func;
}
```

I have to keep commenting and uncommenting...

Comment: "I have no right to change this struct but the struct changes a lot." How does that make sense? Simply enforce the use of a typedef, if people are changing the code anyway.

Comment: remember, in C, `tools` is a datatype, not a variable that you can use member access operator onto it.

Comment: Please be specific... are you required to *define* a matching function (including the function body) or to *declare* a matching function signature? To be honest, if your job is to define the function, then I don't see the value in automatic signature changes, because you would need to re-check the implementation details anyway.

Comment: If the type of variable should be opaque, use a typedef.

Comment: There's a non-standard gcc extension `typeof`

Comment: I don't see how `decltype` can help you much here tbh because if the function signature changes you have to recode the function anyway.

Comment: By the way, despite the fact you are looking for a C++ equivalent facility, I don't think it really warrants the C++ tag.

Comment: @Lundin   See my reedit part.

Comment: @grek40  reedited.

Comment: *"For historical reasons, some of them used int, others used size_t or ssize_t and so on."* You need to get those groups together and set common rules on how to do things. It sounds like you are trying to solve people problem with tech.

Comment: @user694733   lol, yup, maybe you are right...

Comment: So basically, you have `1..N` groups that provide you with code and you want to run the same test on those `N` codes. The signature is the same each time you get code from group `x` but can be different when you get code from group `y`. Maybe you can just define a unique symbol for each of the groups and change your compilation process to include this symbol like `make GROUP=x`. Then all thats left is a preprocessor conditional that enables different function signatures depending on the `GROUP` value.

Comment: @grek40  Great, I'll try  :)

Comment: @Yves I see. Then I think I came up with a work-around, see my answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sane solution is to enforce a `typedef`. If that isn't possible, and the number of alternative types the function could have are limited, as seems to be the case, you could cook up something with C11 `_Generic`.

Instead of having a single function called `my_func`, create multiple functions with different names. Prefix their names depending on the return type. Then have a macro which in turn re-directs to the appropriate function, based on the type passed.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*** the struct that cannot be changed ***/
struct tools {  
    int (*tool_a) (int, int, int);
};

/*** any number of functions with different types ***/
int int_my_func(int a, int b, int c) 
{ 
  puts(__func__); 
}

size_t size_t_my_func(int a, int b, int c) 
{ 
  puts(__func__); 
}

/*** macro to select the appropriate function based on type ***/
#define my_func_typeof(type)                           \
  _Generic( (type),                                    \
            int(*)(int,int,int)    : int_my_func,      \
            size_t(*)(int,int,int) : size_t_my_func)

/*** caller code ***/
int main (void)
{
  struct tools my_tool = {
    .tool_a = my_func_typeof( (struct tools){0}.tool_a )
  };

  my_tool.tool_a(1,2,3);

}
```

Here I used a compound literal `(struct tools){0}.tool_a` to create a dummy object of the same type as `tool_a`, then passed that on to the macro which picks the appropriate function. If the type is not supported, there will be a compiler error since no matching _Generic association could be found.

Comment: Yeah, I always forget about generic selections. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @StoryTeller Still, the typedef version is the sound and most correct one. Code like this is the last resort.

Comment: Nice solution. I am a bit puzzled why you need `##` in your function names in the macro...

Comment: What benefit would we get by a `typedef`? The definition of the function would still have to be changed if that `typedef` is defined differently.

Comment: @Gerhardh Actually the `##` isn't needed indeed at all, it was a remain of my first attempt to solve this. Fixed. Regarding typedef, it is possible to do `typedef int func_t (int, int);` then `func_t func;`.

Comment: Sure you can do `fun_t func;` but this only helps declaring a function with no benefit for defining that function.

Answer (score 6):

Well, this isn't `decltype` but if you can just *convince* your colleague to use a type alias, you can have your static type checking.

If your colleague can be persuaded to do this:

```
typedef int tool_a_prototype(int, int, int);

struct tools {  
    tool_a_prototype *tool_a;
};
```

Then you can declare your functions like this:

```
tool_a_prototype my_tool_a;

int my_tool_a(int a, int b, int c) {
  //Whatever
}
```

And your friendly compiler will tell you if there's a prototype mismatch.

Comment: @Yves - I hope it helps. I'm not sure it answers the question anymore, however. You want type checking or for the need to comment/uncomment to go away?

Comment: Exactly. I just want to stop comment/uncomment anymore. You see I developed my tool yesterday and today many colleagues use it. But they are testing the different versions... So I have to use `int` for group 1, to use `size_t` for group 2... This is really boring...

Comment: Your answer helps a lot anyway. :D   At least I can write a report to my leader...

Comment: One thing to add here is that write the body of the function in such a way that it is compatible with both `size_t` and `int`. Which would mean you might have to introduce some unnecessary casts.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya - Personally I think both `size_t` and `int` should be abstracted by a type alias. Then the body of the function will at least contain only casts to the alias. Either way, this is nasty business the OP is in.

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is that the struct changes a lot, especially the return
>   types, for example int is replaced by size_t today, so I have to
>   change my code a lot.
>
> I know that decltype in C++ can help me so I just want to know if C
>   has something equivalent?

If you are willing to use a **non standard** gcc extension, you can use [`typeof`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html):

```
struct tools {  
    int (*tool_a) (int, int, int);
};

typedef typeof( ((struct tools*)NULL)->tool_a ) tool_a_type;
typedef typeof( ((tool_a_type)NULL)(0,0,0) ) tool_a_return_type;

tool_a_return_type my_func(int x, int y, int z)
{

}

struct tools my_tool = {
    .tool_a = my_func
};
```

Comment: `typeof` is part of C23.