# Typedef members of a struct in C

Tags: c, struct, typedef

**Question:** Can we create an alias for a member of a struct?

Assume we have the following structure with not so helpful variable names (which could themselves be other structures):

```
struct foo {
    type a;
    type b;
    type c;
};
```

Is there a way to essentially do (inside a function) for a specific `struct foo` or all `struct foo`:

```
struct foo my_foo;

typedef my_foo.a protocol;
typedef my_foo.b local;
typedef my_foo.c remote;

// or

typedef (struct foo).a protocol;
```

To use directly as:

```
protocol = ...        // instead of my_foo.a

or

my_foo.protocol = ... // instead of my_foo.a and similar my_bar.a
```

Comment: `typedef` works on types, not variables.

Comment: Just to spare some keystrokes?

Comment: No, you can't do that in C. `my_foo.a`, for instance, isn't a type, so it can't be `typedef`ed. Nor is `protocol`, the way you want to use it, a "type". What are you trying to accomplish? Looks like perhaps you should use macros. *E.g.*, `#define protocol my_foo.a`, then you could write `protocol = ...`. Or you could `#define a protocol` and write `my_foo.protocol = ...`. Be careful about such shortcuts, though, as they may seem convenient at the time, but can lead to a lot of confusion later for a reader of the code.

Comment: "Just to spare some keystrokes?" --- To satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: @lurker Your comment works as an answer for me. Thanks. (If you answer with it I'll be happy to accept it.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C equivalent to C++ decltype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48182676/c-equivalent-to-c-decltype)